# Adobe Premiere - export project with original resolution

Tags: premiere

Trying to import a .mov project at 2312x1644, do some editing, then export at the exact same resolution. I'm new to the program so I assume it has something to do with the codecs, but I don't know which ones to use, or in what order. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this when you export

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A .mov file extension implies that your source material is Apple ProRes (aka Quicktime).  When you import the media, the Project Manager will tell you what type of ProRes it is (422, 422 LT, 422 HQ, etc).  If you use this clip as a basis for a sequence, the sequence will usually inherit the same frame rate, format, aspect ration, pixel shape, etc., of the source material.

After you make your edits, you select the sequence (which contains the clip), the click to File>Export Media.  This will open a dialog box.  One of the options you can choose (it may be a default) is "Match Source".  That solves your resolution, frame rate, and pixel-shape questions.  To export as the same sort of ProRes, select the ProRes (or Quicktime) codec, and then select the appropriate sub-category (422, LT, HQ, etc).  You can then either export directly (using the Export button) or Queue it to Adobe Media Encoder (aka AME), which will then let you export from there.  (If you want to continue using Premiere while exporting, use AME).

Comment: it could also be h.264 just sayin

Comment: …or any of the dozens of other codecs that can be found in a quicktime container.